# Image accuracy metric

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

What is an efficient and correct metric I can use to compare two images in matrix form? I have built a machine learning model which predicts an image and want to see how far off it is from the target using a number for easy comparision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of different methods you can use. I guess the most popular ones are:

1. Euclidean Distance
2. Chord Distance
3. Pearson’s Correlation Coefficient
4. Spearman Rank Coefficient

You can also study about these and other metrics (their main advantages and drawbacks) from here: Image Registration - Principles, Tools and Methods / Authors: Goshtasby, A. Ardeshir

DOI: 10.1007/978-1-4471-2458-0

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which is the best for images related to faces?

Comment: It's hard to say. In machine learning "there is no free lunch". That depends on what kind of face images you are dealing. Which model you are using? These face images have illumination problems? Occlusion? Blur? Different poses? So many things you need to take into consideration. My suggestion is that if you are building your model from scratch, do some research first. If you just want a robust way of identifying faces, try using Oxford Face API for example.

Comment: Do you know if any of these methods are available for torch? I searched but couldn't find any implementations.

Comment: One metric that I forgot to mention but It's also pretty used is the Cosine Similarity Measure. I'm not that familiar with Torch but I'm pretty sure they have this function for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the excellent start from *Victor Oliveira Antonino*, I suggest starting with either Pearson's or Cosine.  The rank coefficient isn't particularly applicable for this space; Euclidean and chord distance have properties that don't represent as well our human interpretations of image similarity.

Each metric has advantages and disadvantages.  When you get into an application that doesn't map readily to physical distance, then Euclidean distance is unlikely to be the best choice.